# connecting to MongDB Shell in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-16.04

To strat mongodb shell, if I use `mongo db` it return permission error concerning the `.mongorc.js file`. I tried with the command `sudo mongo db` and it works well. That means I have a problem with permission parameteres but I don't know how to fixe it. Any ideas ?

This is a screenshot of this situation[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the file permissions you can run:

```
chmod 775 /home/maouici/.mongorc.js

7 - read write and exec to owner
7 - read write and exec to anyone in group owner
5 - read and exec to everyone
```